# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am looking at $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}$$

Absolute divergence can be shown quite easily when using $n!\geq\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$

We get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}$$ which is divergent because of $$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}\geq\frac{\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}}{n^2}=\frac{e^{-1}}{n}$$
However, regular convergence I haven't been able to prove yet, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

The alternating series test should suffice, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}=0$ is also shown easily because of $$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^n}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$
So, the last thing missing is proving decreasing monotonicity of $\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}$ and this is where I need help ;)

I tried some stuff, but none of that lead somewhere, and since I feel like I'm missing something obvious I'm not writing that down for now.
If I don't get answers, I will include what I tried so far.

Comment: You need to note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n = e$ and convergence is monotone.

Comment: By Stirling's formula $\sqrt[n]{n! }=\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}+\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show is for $n\geq1$ $$\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{(n+1)^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n^2}$$$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+2}$$

We have $$\frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\leq\frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)e\leq2e$$
We also have $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+2}\geq e^2$$
It is $2e<e^2$ which completes the proof.